# Input element pattern regular expression does not work

Tags: css, regex, html

I want the field to change to green, as it matches 4 letters followed by 4 numbers, like "blab1111".

This is the regex code: `[A-Za-z]{4}+[0-9]{4}`.
I tried also `^[A-Za-z]{4}+[0-9]{4}$`.

I am using this code:

```css
 input:invalid {
  background: hsla(0, 90%, 70%, 1);
}

input:valid {
  background: hsla(100, 90%, 70%, 1);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' required name='username' autocomplete="off" id='username' pattern="[A-Za-z]{4}+[0-9]{4}" maxlength="50" />
```

The field is not correctly switching to the `:valid` state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` is too much on your regex. Use the following regex: `[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{4}` or `[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}`

```css
input:invalid {
  background: hsla(0, 90%, 70%, 1);
}
input:valid {
  background: hsla(100, 90%, 70%, 1);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' pattern="[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{4}" required name='username' autocomplete="off" id='username' maxlength="50" />

<!-- shorter regex -->
<input type='text' pattern="[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}" required name='username' autocomplete="off" id='username' maxlength="50" />
```

Comment: Oh jeezus. Thank you very much! I tried the regex code with the "+" on the regex101.com website and they told me, it should work. Is the "+" maybe a unregulary problem on some servers?

Comment: At regex101, select JavaScript option when testing JS patterns.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this also,

```
<input type='text' pattern="[A-Za-z]{4}\d{4}" required name='username' autocomplete="off" id='username' maxlength="50" />
```

You can try this pattern as well, but I think some editors not support this,

```
[\u\l]{4}\d{4}
```

`[\u\l]` matches uppercase and lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

`[A-Za-z]{4}`: Alphabet character 4 times.

`+`: Match one or more times. `[A-Za-z]{4}` follows by `+` is a wrong pattern.

`[0-9]{4}`: Nummeric 4 times. It can be short hand by `\d{4}`.

Then, you can remove `required` attribute because it's combined in the pattern.

Correct regex: `[a-zA-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}` or `[a-zA-z]{4}\d{4}`

Comment: *Then, [A-Za-z]{4} one or more times.* is a wrong pattern explanation. The `{4}+` was tested with PCRE option, and it was parsed as a possessive quantifier. And `{4}+` = `{4}` in PCRE. In JS regex, quantifiying a quantifier is not allowed (except for cases like `{1}?` when the `?` makes a lazy limiting quantifier pattern - but again, it makes sense if both bounds are specified, as in `{1,4}?`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I've just edited the explaining